# Django queryset __contains case sensitive?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to perform a simple query:

```
Pizza.object.filter(topping__contains='PEPERONI')
```

Like this, it works like a charm. But if I try that:

```
Pizza.object.filter(topping__contains='peperoni')
```

It is not working.

Do you know why it is case sensitive ? Is there an option to cancel this feature from django ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use `Pizza.object.filter(topping__icontains='peperoni')`.

Filter with [`__icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) check.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to import and use `Q` object:

```py
from django.db.models import Q 

Resulting_Queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(name__istartswith='Nishank Gupta'.strip().lower()) &  Q(name__iendswith='Nishank Gupta'.strip().lower()))
```

This would match `Nishank Gupta` and `Nishank GUPTA`  and  `NisHANnk Gupta` and so on. Hope this helps. Please do let me know your views.

Or Use iexact:

```py
MyModel.objects.filter(name__iexact='Nishank Gupta'.strip().lower())
```

Comment: Note that when you are using `istartswith`, `iexact` etc. you won't need `lower()`